# grep a string within curly brackets {} in a large text file

Tags: r, regex

I have a manuscript I have converted into a text file. It contains many [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier)s of various length contained in curly brackets:

```
{doi: 10.1109/5.771073}
```

I want to grep for the dois and export them into another text file.

Can I use grep such that it returns just the doi, not the whole sentence/vector in which it is located?

Comment: grep() uses patterns.  What is the general pattern for a doi?

Comment: use `str_extract_all` in the `stringr` package. It will be fast and easy.

Answer (score 5):

```
Manuscript = "a lot of text that contains some {doi: 10.1109/5.771073}
some line may contain {doi: 1.2/3.4} and {doi: 5.6/7.8}
Of course other lines may contain nothing interesting"

library(stringr)
Temp = unlist(str_extract_all(Manuscript, "\\{doi:.*?\\}"))
AllDOIs = gsub("\\{doi:\\s*(.*)}", "\\1", Temp)
AllDOIs
[1] "10.1109/5.771073" "1.2/3.4"          "5.6/7.8"
```